# Adding ABRecordRef to NSMutableArray causes error about requiring bridged cast

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray, abrecord

I am getting an error:

> Implicit conversion of C pointer type 'ABRecordRef' (aka 'const void *') to Objective-C pointer type 'id' requires a bridged cast

from this code, trying to add an `ABRecordRef` to an `NSMutableArray`

```
ABRecordRef person = (__bridge ABRecordRef)[contactArr objectAtIndex:i];
[addressBookArray addObject:person];
```

`addressBookArray` is defined as

```
NSMutableArray *addressBookArray;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error message says, you need to re-cast the object in order to put it back into an `NSMutableArray`:

```
ABRecordRef person = (__bridge ABRecordRef)[contactArr objectAtIndex:i];
[addressBookArray addObject:(__bridge ABRecord *)person];
```

[`ABRecord`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/AddressBook/Classes/ABRecord_Class/) is the ObjC class that corresponds to `ABRecordRef`; they're toll-free bridged, so they are interchangeable for this purpose.

---

Note:  `ABRecord` is only available on OS X. If you're on iOS and somehow managed to get those `ABRecordRef`s into an `NSArray` in the first place, you'll have to use `id` for the re-cast

```
[addressBookArray addObject:(__bridge id)person];
```